# How to upload multiple files using webservice with java?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Well, I've searched here about how to make upload files using webservice on java, but without any satisfactory answer.
I need to build a method where i recevie some Strings, and a list of files.
Someone can give me a direction about how to create that webservice where i can upload multiple files?

```
@WebMethod()
public String criarPA(String name, List<File> files)
```

Its something like this... I've already seen that i cant use File... So what can i use instead of?

Comment: a webservice is a really bad way to upload files.  you'll most likely run into memory issues.

Comment: if you _really_ need to do this, you would typically Base64 encode the file bytes and pass that along as a String.

Comment: JTahlborn, can you detail a little more about that Base64 encode? I convert my file into String and send it?

Comment: @Igor using byte[] in SOAP automatically enables base64 encoding. In other words, you don't have to do any manual conversion, just use byte[] as type (see answer by @emka86)

Comment: What is the JAX-WS runtime or better, what is the app server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use File because SOAP protocol used in WebService doesn't have such type. But you can always send array of bytes:

```
@XmlType
public class SoapFile implements Serializable {

  private String fileName;
  private byte[] fileData;

  public String getFileName() {
     return fileName;
  }

  public void setFileName(String fileName) {
     this.fileName = fileName;
  }

  public byte[] getFileData() {
     return fileData;
  }

  public void setFileData(byte[] fileData) {
     this.fileData = fileData;
  }
}
```

And now your code will look something like this:

```
@WebMethod
public String criarPA(List<SoapFile> files)
```

Next you just have to create `File` from byte array saved in `SoapFile` with standard "Java" way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way, you should send a list of byte[]. If you want the name of the file, you should add that attribute as well.

An important thing to note if you are transferring files through Web Services in Java,  you should enable MTOM, which improves performance.
Here is the header of the WS endpoint implemented as a stateless EJB:

```
@WebService 
@WebContext(contextRoot="FileWS")
@MTOM(enabled=true)
@Stateless
public class FileWS implements IFileWS{

    @WebMethod(operationName = "sendFiles", action = "sendFiles")
    public void sendFiles(@WebParam(name = "name")String name, 
        @WebParam(name = "files")ArrayList<byte[]> files) {
```

Answer (score 1):

"File" is not a supported type in java web services.

If you want to know supported types by java web services, refer to this page (section 3.2.3 Using Supported Data Types for Java Web Services) : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15897_01/web.1012/b14027/javaservices.htm

I suggest you implement a web service that upload just one file on server side, then on client side you call this method as much as you have files ;)

Here is a tutorial that implement a java web service for uploading a file : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-devaxis2part3/section2.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way for it is

You can upload the images using SAAJ.

```
The SAAJ API allows you to do XML messaging from the Java platform:
By simply making method calls using the SAAJ API, you can read and write
SOAP-based XML messages, and you can optionally send and receive such 
messages over the Internet (some implementations may not support sending
and receiving).
```

Please check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhg.html#bnbhj) how it works for files.

---

**Creating an AttachmentPart Object and Adding Content:**

```
AttachmentPart attachment = message.createAttachmentPart();

String stringContent = "Update address for Sunny Skies " +
    "Inc., to 10 Upbeat Street, Pleasant Grove, CA 95439";
attachment.setContent(stringContent, "text/plain");
attachment.setContentId("update_address");

message.addAttachmentPart(attachment);
```

or

```
URL url = new URL("http://greatproducts.com/gizmos/img.jpg");
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(url);
AttachmentPart attachment = message.createAttachmentPart(dataHandler);
attachment.setContentId("attached_image");

message.addAttachmentPart(attachment);
```

---

**Accessing an AttachmentPart Object:**

```
java.util.Iterator iterator = message.getAttachments();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart)iterator.next();
    String id = attachment.getContentId();
    String type = attachment.getContentType();
    System.out.print("Attachment " + id + " has content type " + type);
    if (type.equals("text/plain")) {
    Object content = attachment.getContent();
    System.out.println("Attachment contains:\n" + content);
    }
}
```

---

For more clarity on this process check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html#bnbif).